# How can I improve the performance of this directive that transitions opacity on scroll?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, parallax

I've been working on improving this directive for a few hours now but can't seem to take it much further. Can anyone recommend further improvements?

```
.directive("scrollFade", function($window) {
      return function(scope, element, attrs) {

      var ngWindow = angular.element($window);
      var offset = 100;

      function scrollAndFade(){
        var top_of_element = element.offset().top + offset;
        var bottom_of_window = ngWindow.scrollTop() + $window.innerHeight;

        if (top_of_element < bottom_of_window) {
          element[0].style.opacity = 1;
        } else {
          element[0].style.opacity = 0;
        }
      }

      ngWindow.bind("scroll", function() {
        _.debounce(function() {
           window.requestAnimationFrame(scrollAndFade);
        }, 50);
      });

      };
    })
```

I'm using this css for the elements the directive is attached to:

```
transition: opacity .2s ease-in-out;
```

Unscientific performance comparison: 
[image: jquery and javascript comparison]

Comment: Skipping jQuery to compute the height won't "improve performance".

Comment: It's kind of crazy but it did seem to have an effect. Let me explore some more to see if that's real or not.

Comment: @user2864740 completely unscientific nonsense but check out the peaks. They do seem lower. It's very likely that it's cache or scroll speed related or something else. It's just interesting.

Comment: Why do you use `window.requestAnimationFrame`?

Answer (score 0):

I've got 2 suggestions:

- Assuming you're not using element opacity in any watchers or templates elsewhere in your code, I suspect you don't need to call `$scope.apply()`.
- You're debouncing after the call to requestAnimationFrame. You could try debouncing before it, so the event listener on `scroll` is debounced.

  ```
  ngWindow.bind("scroll", function() {
    _.debounce(function() {
       window.requestAnimationFrame(scrollAndFade);
    }, 50);
  });
  ```

  But I suspect this is an extremely minor optimisation in the light of the facts that the only change is opacity, and you're using requestAnimationFrame to further defer the change to when the browser finds it convenient.

Comment: Can you please explain exactly how to do #2? I don't get how to structure it that way.

Comment: @EmptyPockets I've added a code snippet to the answer.

Comment: Thanks @Michal, I updated my post with your suggestions. Removing $scope.apply() works but it seems to break with the snippet you provided. No error, just doesn't work.